# What is a verb for describing the following situation?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is a verb for describing the following situation:

You meet a friend or even a stranger and they talk a lot and you
have to listen to them just being nice.

What verb can I use to describe what I'm doing? e.g. is it called I'm getting a long or going a long or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the clues you gave, I believe you are thinking of

> [go along with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+along+with)
>
> 4. *Fig.* to play along with someone or something; to pretend that you are party to someone's scheme.

This is the closest definition I could find to what you are describe. But I have heard people use it in the sense  that you are describing; in the sense that you are humoring the other person.

Comment: Yea, I agree, `go along` is much better than my `play along`. "Play" implies some verbal/physical acting, while going along is indefinite of any activity.

Answer (score 0):

### Playing along

It's also what you do when someone is pulling a prank on someone else and you somehow get reluctantly involved in the prank.  In order to keep from ruining the prank, you **play along**

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other suggestions, you could use

*bide one's time*

if you are waiting for an opportunity to get out of listening to the person talk on and on.

> Wait quietly for a good opportunity to do something:
>
> *Rich listened obligingly, biding his time as he waited for the right opportunity.*

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bide-one%27s-time?q=bide+one%27s+time))